# How to tell MVAPICH2 to use tcp?

Tags: tcp, mpi, mvapich2

My application produces wrong results, if I use infiniband for the communication between two nodes (using MVAPICH2 as the MPI-implementation).

OpenMPI offers the possibility to specify the network with

```
$ mpirun --mca btl tcp,self ...
```

is there anything similar for MVAPICH2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MVAPICH2 documentation](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/static/media/mvapich/mvapich2-2.1-userguide.html#x1-170004.9) has a spot directly for this. Quoting from their page:

**4.9 Configuring a build for TCP/IP-Nemesis**

The use of TCP/IP with Nemesis channel requires the following configuration:

```
$ ./configure --with-device=ch3:nemesis
```

Both static and shared libraries are built by default. In order to build with static libraries only, configure as follows:

```
$ ./configure --with-device=ch3:nemesis --disable-shared
```

To enable use of the TotalView debugger, the library needs to be configured in the following manner:

```
$ ./configure --with-device=ch3:nemesis  --enable-g=dbg --enable-debuginfo
```

Additional instructions for configuring with TCP/IP-Nemesis can be found in the MPICH documentation available at:  http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/documentation/index.php?s=docs